# How Can i add A specific class to a link using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add add a specific class to all the links in a page using JS but I can not use `getElementById` method as there are several links and I want to add a particular class to each and every one of them how can I do it for example

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<a href="#" class="btn  btn-lg" >Download</a>
<a href="#" class="btn  btn-lg" >Download</a>
<a href="#" class="btn  btn-lg" >Download</a>
<a href="#" class="btn  btn-lg" >Download</a>
<a href="#" class="btn  btn-lg" >Download</a>
<a href="#" class="btn  btn-lg" >Download</a>
</div>
```

I would like to add `btn-info` to all the links using JavaScript how can I do it?

Comment: [`Document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Comment: are you using jquery?

Comment: @t.niese - this isn't a duplicate of that question. This one asks how to select by tag name - "all the links".

Comment: @nnnnnn OP says that `getElementById` (which is even more specific than selecting by class) can not be used because of multiple links should be selected. So select by class is somewhere in between selection all `a` elements which is unlikely for most situations and `getElementById` which only selects one element. It depends on how you interpret the *them*  in `a particular class to each and every one of them`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `document.querySelectorAll()`Method, for that purpose. It gives you freedom to select the elements in many different ways. The main types are based on classes, id, or element name.It can be easily used as,`var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".className")`. Where classname is the name of class which you want to use.

---

For more info, on querySelectorAll() method visit [HTML DOM querySelector() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp)

Comment: That method only returns one element.

Comment: Thanks nnnnnn, for reminding me, I just wanted to talk about  querySelectorAll(), I just wrote that my mistake, I have corrected it now

Comment: it worked for me in this way
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".btn ");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
    {
    elements[i].classList.add("btn-info");
    }

Comment: @Shree ! It's a pleasure to see that your problem has been solved. Keep Learning, Keep Coding !

Answer (score 1):

First you have to get all links using elements method [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) it will return [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) with all elements you need after it you can loop through it and add class to each element.

```
var aElements = document.getElementsByTagName('A');
for (var i = 0; i < aElements.length; i++) {
  aElements[i].classList.push('btn-info');
}
```

[classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) is supported from IE 10, so you can use `aElements[i].className += ' btn-info';` if you have to support lower then 10 versions of IE.

If you would like to add some class for more specific elements, you can use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) instead of `getElementsByTagName`, it still will works for you. `querySelectorAll` returns [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) so it can be used in loop.

Comment: But, if you use document.getElementsByTagName('A'), then it will select all the anchor tags (<a></a>) in the document, I would recommend you to use document.querySelectorAll(), which will ease your work. See my answer below.

Comment: If you like my answer pease upvote it too, it's given below.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery is your friend

```js
$('.btn').addClass('newClass');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <a href="#" class="btn  btn-lg">Download</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn  btn-lg">Download</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn  btn-lg">Download</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn  btn-lg">Download</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn  btn-lg">Download</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn  btn-lg">Download</a>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem. jQuery makes things like that super simple.

Answer (score 0):

Thank You Guys For Your Valuable Support 
Besides Jquery Which Worked Like a Charm my Code Worked in js As shown below

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <a href="#" class="btn  btn-lg" >Download</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn  btn-lg" >Download</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn  btn-lg" >Download</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn  btn-lg" >Download</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn  btn-lg" >Download</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn  btn-lg" >Download</a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".btn ");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
{
    elements[i].classList.add("btn-info");
}
</script>
```